# Не удается установить lamp на ubuntu 20.04

Tags: ubuntu, lamp

Не получается установить lamp на ubuntu 20.04. Apache2 установился и запустился. Дальше ввожу команду: `sudo apt install php8.2 php8.2-mysql php-common php8.2-cli php8.2-json php8.2-common php8.2-opcache libapache2-mod-php8.2` и получаю вот такой ответ:

```
Невозможно найти пакет php8.2
E: Не удалось найти ни один пакет с помощью шаблона «php8.2»
E: Невозможно найти пакет php8.2-mysql
E: Не удалось найти ни один пакет с помощью шаблона «php8.2-mysql»
E: Невозможно найти пакет php8.2-cli
E: Не удалось найти ни один пакет с помощью шаблона «php8.2-cli»
E: Невозможно найти пакет php8.2-json
E: Не удалось найти ни один пакет с помощью шаблона «php8.2-json»
E: Невозможно найти пакет php8.2-common
E: Не удалось найти ни один пакет с помощью шаблона «php8.2-common»
E: Невозможно найти пакет php8.2-opcache
E: Не удалось найти ни один пакет с помощью шаблона «php8.2-opcache»
E: Невозможно найти пакет libapache2-mod-php8.2
E: Не удалось найти ни один пакет с помощью шаблона «libapache2-mod-php8.2»
```

Подскажите, как все-таки установить lamp, я не линуксоид, но lamp мне нужен для учебы.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: Ну, в убунте 20.04 никакого php8.2 никогда не было и не будет, так что тут всё правильно

Comment: «как все-таки установить lamp» — ну например установить именно ту версию php, которая есть в убунте 20.04 https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/php

Comment: посмотрите результат выполнения команды apt search php

Comment: php7.4 установиося после добавления  репозитория. все хорошо. НО! теперь я не могу понять, как в VS Studio Code открывать и, главное, соранять файлы в папке www?

Comment: Зачем вам папка www? Сохраняйте в любую другую

Comment: Поменяйте права доступа к `www`: `sudo chown -R $(id -u):$(id -g) <path-to>/www`. Вуа-ля! Все файлы и папки в `www` отныне принадлежат вам

Comment: с правами доступа разобрался, спасибо! проблема теперь в настройке сервера. делал по этой инструкции: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-apache-web-server-on-ubuntu-22-04. все шло хорошо, до момента, когда надо было протестировать работу сервера, до этого момента: Apache will now be serving your domain name. You can test this by navigating to http://your_domain. не находит он мой файл...